# How do I convert an NSString of hex numbers (@"54 2E") to a byte array?

Tags: ios

I'm trying to take an NSString composed of hexidecimal numbers (without the `\x`) such as `@"54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 20 74 65 73 74 2E"` and save them to a byte array.

Any solution is appreciated.